# Problema inserir no banco de dados MariaDb imagens

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, imagem, mariadb, longblob

Estou usando o MariaDb e um campo LONGBLOB para armazenar minhas imagens, quando mando inserir imagens pequenas (300KB ou menos) insere normalmente, entretanto imagens maiores que isso dá esse erro aqui:

MariaDb [-1] Could not send query: Software caused connection abort: socket write error

```
mar 25, 2019 2:50:23 PM 
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.SwallowedExceptionLogger onSwallowException
ADVERTÊNCIA: An internal object pool swallowed an Exception.
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not send query: Last packet not finished
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.get(SQLExceptionMapper.java:136)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.throwException(SQLExceptionMapper.java:106)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.executeQueryEpilog(MySQLStatement.java:264)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.execute(MySQLStatement.java:288)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.execute(MySQLStatement.java:338)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLConnection.rollback(MySQLConnection.java:244)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.rollback(DelegatingConnection.java:496)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.passivateObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:373)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.returnObject(GenericObjectPool.java:563)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.close(PoolableConnection.java:205)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.closeInternal(DelegatingConnection.java:240)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.close(DelegatingConnection.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.close(PoolingDataSource.java:244)
at sge.persistencia.crud.CrudPersistence$ManagerPoolConnection.liberateResources(CrudPersistence.java:112)
at sge.persistencia.crud.CrudPersistence.liberateConnection(CrudPersistence.java:953)
at sge.processo.agenda.ProcessoRecado.enviarMensagem(ProcessoRecado.java:204)
at sge.apresentacao.agenda.RecadoFrm.enviarMensagem(RecadoFrm.groovy:274)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at sge.seguranca.filtros.FiltroSeguranca.doFilter(FiltroSeguranca.java:40)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at sge.seguranca.filtros.CredencialFilter.doFilter(CredencialFilter.java:32)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:501)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.QueryException: Could not send query: Last packet not finished
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.mysql.MySQLProtocol.executeQuery(MySQLProtocol.java:984)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.execute(MySQLStatement.java:281)
... 57 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Last packet not finished
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.packet.PacketOutputStream.startPacket(PacketOutputStream.java:38)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.packet.commands.StreamedQueryPacket.send(StreamedQueryPacket.java:76)
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.mysql.MySQLProtocol.executeQuery(MySQLProtocol.java:982)
... 58 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O MariaDB, dependendo da instalação e versão, não aceita queries maiores que 300 kB. Ou você tem que enviar o arquivo binariamente em loops incrementais de no máximo 300 kB, ou, no arquivo de configuração do banco de dados, editar a seguinte linha assim:

`max_allowed_packet=25M`

Além disso, se a sua aplicação é Web, seu servidor Web também precisa aceitar anexos deste tamanho. No `php.ini`, por exemplo, seria necessário alterar esta configuração assim (originalmente é 8 MB):

`post_max_size=25M`

Mas claro, isso depende de que softwares você está empregando.